# How to cancel redirection to admin side

Tags: admin, login, activation

My friend asked me to activate a site that someone else did it. The problem is that when I try to run it, and I go to `mysite.com` I arrive to `mysite.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=/`
Where and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disable all plugins or change theme to default one. AFAIK there is no such function by default in WP to redirect non loged in users to login page.

Comment: You are right. It was Members Only plugin.

Comment: :D self explanatory plugin name :D

Answer (score 0):

Since Noone else has responded... i'll take a stab by offering some ideas even though I personally have never had a similar issue.

I assume you've logged in and poked around for some option in the backend?
Otherwise, you can check out .htaccess, and wp-config in your root directory to see if its happening from there.  Also take a look in your theme folder at the index.php or some "home" template if there is one.

Comment: Of course I've checked everything I could think of. I don't see nothing strange in config.php